# Create diff patch for a composer package

Tags: git, composer-php, diff

I'm contributing to quite a large project with lots of submodules, and using `repositories` section of `composer.json` etc.
Sometimes it is handy to edit files in the `vendor` directory instead of the real repository (e.g. there are some submodules with tests for the other ones).

Then I use `composer update` and a message pops up:
`Discard changes [y,n,v,d,s,?]?`

I can choose the option `d`, thus getting a nice diff patch I can later use for the real Git repository. Can I have such a patch in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to dependency directory and use git to show diff:

```
cd vendor/somevendor/somepackage
git diff HEAD
```

This is what Composer is actually doing.

Comment: Composer, at least currently, does not install individual `.git` repos in each package dir, so this won't work.

Comment: It does if you install package from source. In other case you won't get this prompts on `composer update`.