# Is it possible to trigger a GIT diff on a dependancy with composer

Tags: git, composer-php

When updating dependancies via `composer update`, composer checks for modified files apparently using `git status` and later `git diff` should any modifications be found and you chose to view the diff. In these instances, the local dependancies are not themselves stored in local repositories so presumably composer is either temporarily converting the dependancies to repos or copying them to repos so that it can run the git commands on them.

Is there a command that triggers this behaviour and generates a git diff for a given dependency without having to run `composer update`?

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887978/create-diff-patch-for-a-composer-package

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks but the answer doesn't appear to be the case in this instance, dependencies are all in a .gitignore'd and are not themselves repos, so `git diff HEAD` generates a diff of the main project but no changes from the dependancy, however, generating the diff via `composer update` still works so I'm guessing composer must be doing some extra trickery behind the scenes

Comment: For me there is no diff after `composer update` if package is installed from dist archive. And if it is cloned using git, `git diff HEAD` should work as long you're in package directory.